# ESLint: Why is Symbol not defined (no-undef rule)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs, eslint

In a Typescript project that I've recently setup, I've gotten Babel to compile my Typescript code. I'm also using `@typescript-eslint` as my linter. So far, it has been working well until recently when I tried to use `Symbol` in my code.

[image]
For some reason, Typescript (or Babel) is unable to recognise `Symbol` and is giving me an error that `Symbol is not defined`.

Here's how my eslintrc looks:

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2018,
      "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
      "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin"
  ]
}
```

And in my babelrc, I've the following:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    ["@babel/preset-typescript"]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "corejs": 2
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: can you also add your configuration stack, especially eslint and babel. As it is your post lacks a lot

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo Sure, I've added more information about my eslint and babel configuration.

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo Yes, I've a .eslintrc file. I've set it to this `"ecmaVersion": 2018`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the config so far. So other ECMA2015 features work except Symbol?

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo Yes, so far, I don't have any issues until when I tried to use `Symbol`.

Comment: What happens when you mull your config to minima config defined here: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo Do you mean to remove all my configurations in my `eslintrc` file and leave only that `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`? I have a hunch that this issue isn't just with eslint but also either babel or typescript too because after compiling, `Symbol` returns undefined when printed out.

Comment: ```{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2018,
      "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
      "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin"
  ]
}```

Comment: just to narrow the issue

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo Agree. I have just tried to remove that `extends` section from my config but the `Symbol` is still not being recognised.

Comment: I suggest you open an issue with `typescript-eslint` and link this question for people who know better there

Comment: @Carven glad my answer helped! If you don't mind: I updated the question title to reflect your original issue a bit more, as TypeScript was not the problem here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you set `"ecmaVersion": 2018` under `"parserOptions"`, only ES2018 *syntax* is supported by ESLint. For ES6 globals like `Symbol`, you want to specify `env` (enables ES6 syntax supporting automatically, if above was not specified):

.eslintrc.json:

```
{ "env": { "es6": true } }
```

Have a look at their [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options):

> By the same token, supporting ES6 syntax is not the same as supporting new ES6 globals (e.g., new types such as Set). For ES6 syntax, use `{ "parserOptions": { "ecmaVersion": 6 } };` for new ES6 global variables, use `{ "env": { "es6": true } }`. `{ "env": { "es6": true } }` enables ES6 syntax automatically, but `{ "parserOptions": { "ecmaVersion": 6 } }` does not enable ES6 globals automatically.

Comment: this doesn't works for interfaces like `ErrorOptions` or `NodeListOf`